# Align image to edge of second image inside div section

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have two pictures inside , both have the same height, but different width. I would like to position them in this way

1) Image with bigger width (img1) should be place vertically center
2) Image with shorter width should be align to left edge of previous image

Finally I want to get something like this image below

[image]

What should I change in my code

```
<div>
    <img src="img1"/>
    <img src="img2"/>
<div/>
```

Comment: `img { float: left; clear: left; }`

Comment: Will this work? http://jsfiddle.net/6TeFX/2/ I mathematically found where to put the margin.. that may be your best hope :(

Comment: If that doesn't work, I can keep trying some more stuff with jsfiddle and get back to you on that? I used two divs instead of pictures but you can easily make that swap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div{padding:20px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
img{float:left; clear:right}
```

Comment: 20px doesn't assure that first image will be placed centrally

Comment: Your representation doesn't fit with your explenation then, no?

Answer (score 0):

First you'd like to assign ids to your images:

```
<div>
    <img id="img1" src="img1"/>
    <img id="img2" src="img2"/>
<div/>
```

Then:

```
#img1 {
text-align: center;
}
#img2 {
 /* Your desired values */;
}
```